# Jquery Datatables cant get the sum value of multiple columns

Tags: datatables

I have a table which is perfectly populating data. There is a shipping cost column which needs to be calculated and shown in a div which is outside the table. I have got the value summed up but how to pass the value to the data table so that it can be populated elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you pass a calculated sum to the dataTable, so it can pass it to a `<div>`? At first I thought you wanted dataTable to calculate sum and return it, so I made this extension or "plugin" up :

```js
//pass columnIndex that needs to be calculated
//and the $(element) that should receive the calculated value
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnColumnSum = function ( oSettings, iColIndex, oElement ) {
    var value,
        total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<oSettings.aoData.length;i++) {
        value = oSettings.aoData[i]._aData[iColIndex];
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            total = total + parseFloat(value);
        }
    }
    oElement.text(total);
}
```

Now DataTable is extended so you can call for example

```js
dataTable.fnColumnSum(3, $("#shipping-costs"));
```

jsfiddle with the above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jTgx2/**

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code worked for me. I hope it will help you too.

```
$("#cashSheet").dataTable({
    "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display){
        var api = this.api(), data;
        var intval = function(i){
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1:
            typeof i === 'number' ?
            i : 0;
        };
        total = api
            .column( 3 )
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b){
                return intval(a) + intval(b);
            }, 0 );
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 3, {page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b){
                return intval(a) + intval(b);
            }, 0 );
        $(api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
            ''+pageTotal +' ( '+ total + ' total)'
        );
        total = api
            .column( 4 )
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b){
                return intval(a) + intval(b);
            }, 0 );
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 4, {page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b){
                return intval(a) + intval(b);
            }, 0 );
        $(api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
            ''+pageTotal +' ( '+ total + ' total)'
        );
    }
});
```

It calculates the sum of fourth and fifth column and displays it in the footer. Hope it helps you. All the best.

Comment: Could pls share the `<table>` html

Answer (score 0):

> try this instead of writing same function multiple time

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {

        "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(),
                data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function(i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$a-zA-Z, ]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
            };

            var cols = [4, 5]; // your columns position will come in this array

            for (let index = 0; index < cols.length; index++) {
                var col_data = cols[index];
                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(col_data)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function(a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Total over this page
                pageTotal = api
                    .column(col_data, {
                        page: 'current'
                    })
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function(a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Update footer
                $(api.column(col_data).footer()).html(
                    'Total: ' + pageTotal + ' ( GrandTotal: ' + total + ' )'
                );
            }

        },

    } );
} );
```